# Figuring out an struct in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, constructor

I am doing the "Game of life" as an assignment for the college, the tutor has given to us part of the code, but I am having problem for understand  two parts.

First:

```
grid(int scale) : scale_(scale), width_(problem_definition::width(scale)), height_(problem_definition::height(scale)), data_(new problem_definition::data_type[width_*height_])
```

Until I can understand is the moment that he requests for the memory which is used for the grid for the simulation. However, I can not grasp the syntax beyond the new. why are those brackets with an empty space? what does mean the colon after grid (int scale)?

Second:

```
void initialize()
{
for (std::size_t y = 0; y < height_; ++y)
{
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < width_; ++x)
    {
        at(x,y) = problem_definition::initialize(x, y, scale_);
    }
}
```

}

what is this "at()" inside the second for loop?

I would appreciate any insight  here is the full struct definition:

```
struct grid
{
  grid(int scale) : scale_(scale), width_(problem_definition::width(scale)), height_(problem_definition::height(scale)), data_(new problem_definition::data_type[width_*height_])
{

}
void initialize()
{
    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < height_; ++y)
    {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < width_; ++x)
        {
            at(x,y) = problem_definition::initialize(x, y, scale_);
        }
    }
}
problem_definition::data_type at(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, int dx, int dy)
{
    if (dx<0 && -dx>x) return problem_definition::out_of_bounds_value();
    if (dy<0 && -dy>y) return problem_definition::out_of_bounds_value();
    if (x + dx >= width_) return problem_definition::out_of_bounds_value();
    if (y + dy >= height_) return problem_definition::out_of_bounds_value();
    return at((int)x + dx, (int)y + dy);
}
problem_definition::data_type& at(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    return data_[x + y*width_];
}
void swap(grid& other)
{
    std::swap(scale_, other.scale_);
    std::swap(width_, other.width_);
    std::swap(height_, other.height_);
    std::swap(data_, other.data_);
}
void print(std::ostream& str)
{
    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < height_; ++y)
    {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < width_; ++x)
        {
            str << at(x, y);
        }
        str << std::endl;
    }
}
private:
 int scale_;
 std::size_t width_;
 std::size_t height_;
 std::unique_ptr<problem_definition::data_type[]> data_;
};
```

Comment: The colon and subsequent code after the constructor is an [initialiser list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It initialises the class's fields i.e. assigns to them some values.

Comment: And at() is just a method returning a reference to an element in the grid data_ - shorthand for data_[x + y*width_]

Comment: This is quite a convoluted question. On this site you're better off asking one well defined question rather than asking for open-ended assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add some white space to the first line to make it easier to read:

```
grid(int scale) : scale_(scale),
                  width_(problem_definition::width(scale)),
                  height_(problem_definition::height(scale)),
                  data_(new problem_definition::data_type[width_*height_])
```

Now we can easily see the colon (a `:` is a colon, a `;` is a semicolon) defines an initialiser list which takes a series of `var(value)` pairs and assigns each `value` to each `var`.

I don't see any "brackets with an empty space" so can't answer that. But beyond `new` is just a standard array type of the form: `element_type[length]`. The element type is `problem_definition::data_type` and the array is of length `width_` times `height_`.

Finally, `at()` is just a function call that returns a reference. If you study the function definition:

```
problem_definition::data_type& at(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    return data_[x + y*width_];
}
```

then you can see the line with the call to `at()`, via the magic of references, is the same as the following:

```
data_[x + y*width_] = problem_definition::initialize(x, y, scale_);
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I correct the colon (semicolon) in the question.